# Check if emoji exist in a string [BASH]

Tags: regex, bash, emoji

I'm trying to figure out if an emoji is present in a string as a substring in Bash 4.3.11

```bash
emoji="[\uD800-\uDBFF]"
[[ "" =~ $emoji ]] && echo "Emoji found!"
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

try using pattern matching, encoding code points to utf-8 bytes:

```
emoji=$'\xed[\xa0-\xaf][\x80-\xbf]'
[[ "..." = *$emoji* ]] && echo found
```